# Laravel model json column cast nested element

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a User model that stored credentials as json in db.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'credentials' => 'array',
    ];
}

$user = User::find(1);
$user->credentials = ['username' => 'john', 'pass' => 'mypass'];
$user->save();
```

How do I to make the model class cast the `pass` element of the `credentials` array?

This doesn't seem to work:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'credentials' => 'array',
    'credentials->pass' => 'encrypted',
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following the @hitesh answer I found the way to do it correctly, which is to use accessors and mutators and remove array casting from the model and use `json_decode` and `json_encode` for the value in the accessor and the mutator respectively, otherwise there'll be an error with array casting.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function getCredentialsAttribute(string $value): array
    {
        $value = json_decode($value, true);

        if (isset($value['pass'])) {
            $value['pass'] = decrypt($value['pass']);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setCredentialsAttribute(array $value): void
    {
        if (isset($value['pass'])) {
            $value['pass'] = encrypt($value['pass']);
        }

        $this->attributes['credentials'] = json_encode($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel as of now (10.x) doesn't support this type of casting. For now you can only use "->" in updating nested keys.

```
$user = User::find(1);
 
$user->update(['credentials->pass' => 'mypass']);
```

You can read more in the [official documentation regarding array casting](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

If you really need to cast nested values you will have to define your own attribute accessors/mutators for 'credentials' and do all the transformations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @d3jn in the answer, It was better to add the accessors/mutators. Please check below whole User model code.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'credentials' => 'array',
    ];

    public function getCredentialsAttribute($value)
    {
        if(isset($value['pass'])) {
            $value['pass'] = decrypt($value['pass']);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function setCredentialsAttribute($value)
    {
        if(isset($value['pass'])) {
            $value['pass'] = encrypt($value['pass']);
        }
        $this->attributes['credentials'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `Array to string conversion` for that attribute, I guess it doesn't work with arrays

Comment: well, I had to remove array casting and add `json_encode($value)` and `json_decode($value)` in the mutator and accessor respectively.